# Will Perl be the bottleneck in this kind of image processing?

Tags: java, performance, perl, image-processing, bufferedimage

The processing I have in mind is this:

- there are thousands of png files
- each of them should be loaded, and its pixels accessed
- each pixel's channels will be processed in some way, and then written to a binary file

I was thinking of using some sort of module, like ImageMagick wrappers, or some other wrapper for a C image processing backend. Will Perl slow me down if I choose it to implement this task? I have a tool already that's written in Java ( it uses JDK's BufferedImage ), and it's reasonably fast. Would I be crazy to expect the same speed from Perl?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you're using ImageMagick, or other any other C-based processing tool, perl will most certainly not be the bottleneck.  The bottlenecks I could see (especially if processing thousands of files) would be:

- Disk IO speeds
- Memory access speeds
- Library algorithm speed

Perl will make a great glue for doing what you want.  The slow parts will still be slow.  You might as well make the fast parts easy. :)

Also, remember the two Rules of Optimization:

1. Don't do it.
2. (For experts only: ) Don't do it yet.

When you do get it put together, run a profiler on it.  If and when that becomes your goal, check out:

http://metacpan.org/pod/Devel::NYTProf

Devel::NYTProf is pretty much the bee's knees when it comes to profiling tools.  It'll show you exactly where your slowdowns are, so you don't just have a "warm fuzzy" feeling that you have it right...you'll know for sure.

Answer (score 4):

I don't think so, unless your Perl code is over-reliant on method calls in a tight loop.
But if the actual image processing is done in C backend, Perl will not be a bottleneck performance-wise.

Comment: The only C backend will be the one exposed by the module's API. I'm not planning on writing C myself :)

Comment: @Geo: I suspect that the "C backend" DVK referred to was "ImageMagick... or some other wrapper for a C image processing backend". The actual image processing will be handled by ImageMagick (or whatever other graphics lib) and will probably be the most time-consuming part of the operation, so it doesn't much matter what language you use to call the library.

Comment: @Dave - yep, that's what I meant

Answer (score 3):

The answer depends on what is limiting performance in the Java version.  If you're limited by file I/O (including .png decompression), then moving to Perl will probably be fine.  Otherwise, you're likely to pay a steep performance penalty for processing each pixel in Perl, but if you can call C routines to process entire images, you're likely to be just as fast (possibly faster, depending on the relative performance of the C and Java libraries).

So, in brief: if Perl must touch pixels, it will be slow.  If Perl touches images and C touches pixels, it's probably fine.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, I expect the performance of a perl implementation would be incredibly sucky at pixel-level image manipulation.

Yes, you could do it, but Perl's data structures don't lend themselves to this kind of thing. If you were using a library where you don't need to make 1x call per pixel, you'll be fine though.

Comment: I'd need to get the pixel at each X,Y location and then process it using Perl code ( simple byte extraction ).

Comment: You'd probably want to put the image into a raw bitmap in a single perl scalar - then use slicing to get the appropriate bytes out. That would suck, but not as much as using Perl arrays. It'd still be slow for processing lots of big images - at least much slower than something like Java which can properly optimise code on byte arrays (I imagine) - and that's assuming you had libraries which were efficent for loading / saving to PNG or whatever.